# Angular 6 : DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: https://example.com/ngsw_worker.es6.js.map

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, angular6, angular-service-worker

I converted my angular 6 application to PWA using the Angular CLI (ng add  @angular/pwa). I only have one project in my directory and so I ran this command without specifying project name.

After deployment, the service worker registers - and everything seems to be in order expect i get the following error in google chrome console:

DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: https://example.com/ngsw_worker.es6.js.map

What does this error mean? And how can it be fixed/avoided? Thank you!

Comment: Look like it's an open issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23596

Answer (score 5):

Go to `angular.json` and set the desired `sourceMap` of configurations to `true`.

In example, follow `projects` -> `<project-name>` -> `architect` -> `build` -> `configurations` -> `production` (or any environment you are using) -> and change `sourceMap: false` to `sourceMap: true`.

Comment: Whats the cause for this warning?

Comment: Silly question perhaps, but would this result in source code being easily accessible and legible in production via Chrome DevTools?