# angular service worker ngsw_serviceworker.es6.js.map not found

Tags: javascript, angular, progressive-web-apps

I have registered a service worker with angular 4, when build in prod mode over https it console a message 
DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: https://www.somewebsite.com/ngsw_worker.es6.js.map

My Package.json file

```
{
  "name": "healthcare",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "sw": "sw-precache --root=dist --config=precache-config.js",
    "static-serve": "cd dist && live-server --port=4200 --host=localhost --entry-file=/index.html",
    "build-prod-ngsw": "ng build -prod && node_modules/.bin/ngsw-config dist ./src/ngsw-config.json && cp node_modules/@angular/service-worker/ngsw-worker.js ./dist/ngsw-worker.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "6.0.6",
    "@angular/common": "6.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.0.6",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.6",
    "@angular/forms": "6.0.6",
    "@angular/http": "6.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.6",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.6.8",
    "@angular/router": "6.0.6",
    "@angular/service-worker": "6.0.6",
    "angular-sweetalert-service": "^2.0.2",
    "angular2-cookie": "^1.2.6",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^11.1.1",
    "ngx-owl-carousel": "^2.0.7",
    "ngx-snackbar": "^1.2.0-rc.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.1",
    "sw-precache-webpack-dev-plugin": "^0.2.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "^3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "6.0.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.4",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "sw-precache": "^5.2.1",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "^0.11.5",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "2.7.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking and properly format your code. That will make it much easier for us to help you!

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50862170/angular-6-devtools-failed-to-parse-sourcemap-https-example-com-ngsw-worker